# prompt cl commands from a program

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am trying to design a screen that will present to the user, a list if options to execute CL commands such as WRKSBSD, WRKJOBD etc. I had assumed that executing the command from within the program would display the command screen the same way it would have, had the user pressed F4 to prompt the command parameters. But as I found out, executing the command from within a CL program without the mandatory parameters passed in results in an error. Is there any way to display the command prompt screen while executing it within a program?

Answer (score 3):

Put a question mark in front of the command name and it will prompt.
There are also ways of making it prompt only individual parameters, but sounds like the single ? up front would do the job here.